# Is it right/safe to show sql in asp.net code(.aspx file)?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, security, gridview, sqldatasource

Let's take this code as example:

```
<div style="overflow:auto;width:700px;"> 
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
                    AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True"
                    AutoGenerateEditButton="True" DataMember="DefaultView" 
                    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                    DataKeyNames="..." CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" Width="90%"
                    Height="90%" Font-Size="Small">
                    <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
                    <Columns>.
                             .
                             .
                        <asp:CommandField DeleteText="delete" ShowDeleteButton="True"></asp:CommandField>
                    </Columns>                    
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                </asp:GridView>

                </div>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DBUserConnectionString %>"                     
                    SelectCommand="SELECT ... FROM ... "
                    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM ... WHERE ...=@...;">
                    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Since I'm new to VB and ASP I'm using the sqlDatasource to fill the Gridview **without VB code behind**(please note this), everything is being shown in the aspx code. When I run it with browser and see the source code it only shows html and alot of `javascript:__doPostBack`'s, no connection, no tables, not even asp controls.
However i'd like to know if this is the right way to fill griviews and if it is really safe, I mean is there a way see .aspx code on browser?

Comment: It's as safe as your webserver. All asp.net controls are translated to html whereas the declarative datasource controls like `SqlDataSource` are serverside controls only. So nothing is visible at the client.

Comment: Should be safe.  Provided your server is setup right and there's no other security vulnerabilities allowing access to your file system, it's not possible to see the server side code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's equally safe as putting it in code behind.  However, you really should be putting this sort of thing in code behind so you can separate your logic from your view.

Comment: I don't think you should have SQL in **code-behind**, or these SQL queries become coupled to this `Form`. You should have a DataAccess library, and use either ADO.NET or Entity Framework within this library.  This will make it re-useable.

Comment: @christiandev Good point.  Ideally, you have a Data Access layer, and call THAT from the code-behind.  Sorry for any confusion I may have introduced.

Answer (score 0):

I don't generally put my SQL queries in codebehind as a matter of habit.  I prefer to use webservices called by a Data Portal class which call stored procedures.